# Powershell - Unable to disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS for a website

Tags: powershell, authentication, iis, anonymous

When I use the following Powerhell script the anonymous authentification for the my website in IIS is not changing from 'Enabled' to 'Disabled'. Could anybody help please:-

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name enabled -value false -PSPath IIS:\Sites\myWebsite -Force
```

I also tried this:-

```
    Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name disable -value true -PSPath IIS:\Sites\myWebsite -Force
```

I have also tried:-

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication' -name enabled -value false -PSPath IIS:\Sites\myWebsite -Force
```

I have also tried this but stil does not work:-

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name Enabled -value False -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Location "Sites\myWebsite"
```

I am not getting any errors. It appears that the script runs successfully.

Also, does anybody know how I would set forms Authentication to disabled too?

So looks like I am able to set the authentication to 'Enabled' if I do this:-

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name Enabled -value true -Location "IIS:\Sites\myWebsite"
```

But I can not set the Authentication to 'Disabled' if I do this:-

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name Enabled -value false -Location "IIS:\Sites\myWebsite"
```

Comment: not sure this will work but maybe try wrapping your filter in single quotes?  small possibility that it's reading the `/` as an escape char.

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for helping, but unfortunately this did not work :-(.

Comment: can you try to write False instead of false

Comment: or this: `Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value False -PSPath IIS:\ -Location "Sites\myWebsite"`

Comment: Hi Martin I tried what you suggested but got an error.

Comment: Set-WebConfigurationProperty : Filename: 
Error: Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Sites\myWebsite'
At C:\Users\andrew.short\Documents\Software\Power Shell\Untitled11.ps1:16 char:29+ Set-WebConfigurationProperty <<<<  -Filtersystem.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name Enabled -value False -PSPath 'IIS:\' -Location"Sites\myWebsite"
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-WebConfigurationProperty], FileNotFoundException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.SetConfigurationPropertyCommand

Answer (score 2):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -name enabled -value false -PSPath IIS:\\ -location ${site_name}/${virtual_directory_name}
```

This should do what you want.  Ran with enabled values of both true and false and verified in IIS.

Comment: I can confirm it also works whether you use $True/$False or true/false.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have the solution:-

```
Set-WebConfiguration system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -PSPath IIS:\ -Location myWebsite -Value @{enabled="True"}
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work as IIS asks for a 'name' for the parameter. I set this to -Name Enabled but then get the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely work just check your IIS path correctly..

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -name enabled -value false -location "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\NMFD"
```

Comment: This doesn't change the value for me, but the answer by @BrianH works.

Answer (score 0):

In case non of above worked and if someone is still looking for answer this worked for me

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication' -Name enabled -Value False -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'
```

Basically I took PSPath from below command

```
Get-WebConfiguration -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication 'iis:\sites\Default Web Site' |select *
```

Comment: This gives: `Set-WebConfigurationProperty : This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default
(overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".`

Comment: Are you sure you have all required IIS features turned on in your windows server?